# How to be sure that running process is real application

Tags: c#, hash, process

I want to check if there is a real notepad.exe is running. Can I check process hash with its executable path?

I use Process.GetProcessesByName for this, but if there is another notepad.exe developed by me is running in process list, my code will return result. But there is no real notepad application running.

Comment: but how to define term **real**, that it the question

Comment: Would `process.MainModule.FileName` help?

Comment: I mean i want to check hash of the running process with its real executable. Is it more clear?

Comment: Once you have the full path of the executable, you can calculate a hash over this file. But what do you mean by "hash of the running process"?

Comment: Yes i was thinking that. Thanks this is the answer.